# When to use Cursors and While Loops in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, while-loop, cursor

On what factors do we choose between a Cursor and a while loop. When should we use Cursors and when should we use While loops?

Comment: You should avoid both. Avoid RBAR, always go for Set based.

Answer (score 3):

Cursors are a looping construct built inside the database engine and come with a wide variety of features. Cursors allow you to fetch a set of data, loop through each record, and modify the values as necessary; then, you can easily assign these values to variables and perform processing on these values. Depending on the type of cursor you request, you can even fetch records that you've previously fetched.

Because a cursor is an actual object inside the database engine, there is a little overhead involved in creating the cursor and destroying it. Also, a majority of cursor operations occur in tempdb, so a heavily used tempdb will be even more overloaded with the use of cursors.

A WHILE loop is a programming construct that you're likely familiar with from other programming languages. You define a condition at the beginning of the loop, and iteration will occur so long as this condition remains to be true.

WHILE loops are as easy to use as a cursor, but sometimes these constructs are a little more difficult to read and/or to understand, as a query must occur on the base table(s) that must fetch a single next row. This type of operation is very tricky to do in situations where your underlying base table does not have a primary key column (which it should have).

WHILE loops don't provide some of the bells and whistles that come with cursors, such as the ability to easily go "backward" in the result set. Although, I've never been in a situation in which I did anything other than a straight loop through a result set with a cursor.

One advantage of the WHILE loop is that no objects must be created in memory to facilitate the looping through a set of records as is necessary with a cursor.

**EDIT**

If you want to analyze the functionality of both, you can write a statement with cursor as well as while loop and analyze the number of reads performed using SQL Server Profiler. This tool will give me a combined aggregation of the reads taken for each record rather than each individual record. The rule of thumbs says, whichever is faster, is better.